# Can you make/insert tables inside every row in a table of a database in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

Is it possible? If yes, how?

I am using xampp for my database and I wanted to make a database with "students" table, only one column for the list of student IDs, and every student ID has another table inside. (I was considering making tables for every student ID so that it can be done directly but it seems that it PHP/MySQL does not allow integers as table name).

Comment: No, It is not possible. A student should be a row in the student database. If you are creating tables for entities you want to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot put tables inside a row in SQL. That's not compatible with the concept of a relational database. What you can do is provide a foreign key to another table where you can collect the data you need to link to your first table.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is to have one table with all you want about the students, and add a field with their ID.

So, yo don't have to get the information from student #123 as

SELECT * FROM 123

but

SELECT * FROM students_table WHERE IdStudent = 123